# how to store error info occuring during loadtest in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

During the load test http 5XX or 4XX occur. the summary report show the error% but i see no way to see the details of the error.

usually in other load testing tools i am able to generate error graph which shows when it occurred and the request and response details.

In jmeter what do i have to do to capture this information for later analysis.

I tried to use "tree result listener" but this is usually good for one user run for debugging purpose and not for on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got error details with "view result tree". If you want see error then you have to check  "Log/Display Only: Error". [image]

You can display various information with "Graph", but the "Graph" in Jmeter is very limited.

You can capture information in different Formats XML or CSV. You have to add "Report" then you can configure what you want to capture.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the help could you tell me how to get Latency info in my csv file. "Save Latency" is selected but i am not able to see it in the csv report